# Hide Touch Selection grippers from UWP RichEditBox

Tags: uwp, touch, richeditbox

I have created a UWP app which used RichEditBox to display contents of a file having multiple lines. Based on the selection changed events from the control, line is selected and further actions are performed in the user interface.

However, when I tap the same line again, the grippers appear. I would want to complete avoid showing the grippers as this allows moving the selection over a range of lines which does not serve any purpose in the app.

The gripper appears on touch devices. I want the gripper to be hidden, and would like to know if there is a programmatic way to do this.

[Touch Selection Gripper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMMI8.png)

Comment: Please check my udpates

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

If I understand you correctly, you want to prevent the selection text change from user's action. A possbile workaround for your requirement is that you could handle the [RichEditBox.SelectionChanging Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.richeditbox.selectionchanging?view=winrt-22621) when user wants to move and select other text. In the SelectionChanging, you could manually set the selection text of the `RichEditBox` to the original text. The behavior looks like the drag text function is disabled.

Here is the code that I used for test.

**Xaml Part:**

```
 <RichEditBox x:Name="MyRichEditBox" Width="800" Height="300" SelectionChanging="RichEditBox_SelectionChanging" />
```

**Code-behind**

```
 public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        //for test purpose, i manually set the selectioned text at the begining
        MyRichEditBox.Document.SetText(Windows.UI.Text.TextSetOptions.None, "This is some sample text");
        var selectedText = MyRichEditBox.Document.Selection;
        selectedText.SetRange(3, 15);
    }
    private void RichEditBox_SelectionChanging(RichEditBox sender, RichEditBoxSelectionChangingEventArgs args)
    {
        //when selection starts to change, keep the selection back to original one
        var selectedText = MyRichEditBox.Document.Selection;
        selectedText.SetRange(3, 15);
    }
```

**Old replay:**

I have to say that showing the gripper is the default behavior of TextBox in UWP. We can't modify it now.

Besides, I noticed that the gripper should appears when running on touchable devices like a surface. When running the app on my PC, there is no gripper when I select the text in the RichEditBox.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The target device where the control must be rendered is on a touch device and showing grippers would not be ideal. When the grippers appears, the next thing that can be done is to drag this over multiple lines. If we cannot hide grippers, is there a way to prevent/override the drag operations from gripper being executed ?

Comment: @APM A workaround is to manually set the selection text when the selection text is going to change by use action. I've updated my answer and you could check my workaround.

Comment: The workaround does not work. Are there any other ideas ?

Comment: @APM What do you mean by it does not work? The behavior you got should looks like the drag function is disabled and you can't change the selection.